# Deploying to EC2 with chef and knife

Tags: deployment, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I'm trying to deploy an instance to `ec2` with the `knife` command line tool for `chef`. Running

```
knife --version
```

gives `Chef: 11.14.0.alpha.1`

I've configured my `knife.rb` file appropriately

```
knife[:aws_access_key_id] = 'ABSDGYRB7KXSFHGSF'
knife[:aws_secret_access_key] = 'SDHGsdbstsdsdgdfhdfAGSDGC5IOfqsdgdfhAS'
knife[:flavor] = 't1.micro'
knife[:aws_ssh_key_id] = 'myawskey'
knife[:identity_file] = "/Users/place/pem/myawskey.pem"
```

However when I run

```
knife ec2 server list
```

I get

```
FATAL: Cannot find sub command for: 'ec2 server list'
The ec2 commands were moved to plugins in Chef 0.10
You can install the plugin with `(sudo) gem install knife-ec2
```

But I've installed the package several times, each time with the same result.

```
Successfully installed knife-ec2-0.8.0
Parsing documentation for knife-ec2-0.8.0
Done installing documentation for knife-ec2 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

**What could be causing this, and what can I do to fix it?**

I feel like it might have something to do with the alpha version of chef I'm running, but that's the version the [chef developer kit](http://www.getchef.com/downloads/chef-dk/) installed so I'd like to imagine it would be stable. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://github.com/opscode/chef-dk/issues/36) turned out to fix the problem.

First step:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

followed by:

```
sudo chef gem install knife-ec2
```